# Trigger Email send to an internal Mailbox with fields the Customer filled out in the Clouldpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, triggered-send, cloudpage

we want to send an trigger email, which should be routed to an internal emailbox  after the customer filled out a Cloudpage. the values of the fields the customer has filled out should be displayed in the trigger send.

So far I have found an AMP script to send an trigger to  a customer, I am wondering if the solution could be to hard code the internal inbox into the Script.

Is there any downside or maybe an easier way to implement?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Does it need to be a real time trigger, or can it be a scheduled update email?

Comment: First we thought about  a real time trigger, now I try with automation and a user-initiated Email as Notification  to have send it every hour. I try to use SQL selection based on timestamp to retrieve the Information inserted into the Cloudpage

Comment: Sorry I am confused, does this mean you resolved the issue by using the automation, or that you tried it and failed to get it to work?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I will try it with Automation since this seems to be easier to solve, I will post if I succeed.Thank you